# Detecting the vehicle signal light of a moving vehicle using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

Hi i m really really new to image processing and matlab.

i tried to detect vehicle of a traffic video using 'vision.forgroundDetector'in matlab.

But now i want to identify the vehicle signal light is on or off when the vehicle is turning.

i tried some codes but it never work and i dont know where to write the code also the written code didn't work.

Can someone please help me to identify the signal light of moving vehicle.
you can find the video that i have used through this link 
 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjlBnrzSGjc"

Here is my code:

```
    foregroundDetector = vision.ForegroundDetector('NumGaussians', 3, ...'NumTrainingFrames', 50);

videoReader = vision.VideoFileReader('vi.mp4');
for i = 1:150 

    figure; imshow(frame); title('Video Frame');
figure; imshow(foreground); title('Foreground');




    videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Name', 'Detected Cars');
    videoPlayer.Position(3:4) = [650,400];  % window size: [width, height]
    se = strel('square', 3); % morphological filter for noise removal

    no = {'0','00-0000'};
    num =1;
    k = 10;
    m=0




    while ~isDone(videoReader)

    frame = step(videoReader); % read the next video frame

    % Detect the foreground in the current video frame
    foreground = step(foregroundDetector, frame);

    % Use morphological opening to remove noise in the foreground
    filteredForeground = imopen(foreground, se);

    blobAnalysis = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
    'AreaOutputPort', false, 'CentroidOutputPort', false, ...
    'MinimumBlobArea', 150);

    % Detect the connected components with the specified minimum area, and
    % compute their bounding boxes
    bbox = step(blobAnalysis, filteredForeground);

    % Draw bounding boxes around the detected cars
    result = insertShape(frame, 'Rectangle', bbox, 'Color', 'green');

    % Display the number of cars found in the video frame
    numCars = size(bbox, 1);
    m = m+ numCars;   
%st = {'JRW-2731','BCR-5890','WJ-6629','MW-5587','RV-6929','BN-8944','AN-7037','BI-7899','BI-7899','RX-7294','TL-9090'};
 noplat;

    result = insertText(result, [10 50; 10 100], no, 'BoxOpacity', 1, ...
        'FontSize', 14);

    step(videoPlayer, result);  % display the results
%    step(videoPlayer, result1);
end

release(videoReader); % close the video file
```

This is the next File;

```
    if m>6800 && k == 10
        no = {'1','DAE-4321'};
        k = k-1;
        end
     if m>9600 && k==9
        no = {'2','204-0024'};
        k = k-1;
        end
     if m>15000 && k==8
        no = {'3','QK-BG18'};
        k = k-1;
        end
     if m>23700 && k==7
        no = {'4','KT-7349'};
        k = k-1;
        end
     if m>25000 && k==6
        no = {'5','K2-1479'};
        k = k-1;
     end
     if m>25800 && k==5
        no = {'6','BG-5218'};
        k = k-1;
        end
     if m>33300 && k==4
        no = {'7','B2-8697'};
        k = k-1;
        end
     if m>37900 && k==3
        no = {'8','PQ-1374'};
        k = k-1;
     end   
     if m>90500 && k==2
        no = {'9','RX-7294'};
        k = k-1;
     end
     if m>97000 && k==1
        no = {'10','TL-9090'};;
        k = k-1;
     end
```

Comment: this is not a beginner's problem and I doubt that your video material allows a robust solution.

Comment: @Piglet yes might be. But i m software engineering student and just tried to do this task but i failed this was my first time to do image processing and matlab.If you can please help me to achieve it

Comment: and I'm a senior image-processing professional and I tell you that a) people who do image-processing for the first time usually count white pixels on a black background or something of similar complexity there are many good reasons for that b) your video is not suitable. it lacks the necessary resolution. using that you'll never find a robust solution in that noisy daylight environment focus on a single lane. you're wasting your time. maybe you get a few indicators right with luck. you usually don't do brain surgery on your first day at medical university right? no offense

Comment: I'm a physician, and I have to agree with @Piglet. :)